# Selecionar Números em uma tabela HTML pelo table data

Tags: javascript, html

Eu possuo uma tabela com vários "td"(table data) e gostaria de adaptar um código em Javascript que selecionasse esses valores de dentro do "td" e fizessem comparações para que, por exemplo, quando o valor dentro do "td"  estiver acima de 5 o numero fique em vermelho.

Porém é uma tabela com tanto numérico quanto string. exemplo:

```
    <tbody id ="tbl">
    <tr>  
        <td>açaí</td>
        <td>2</td>
     </tr>     
      <tr>  
        <td>Coco</td>
        <td>6</td>
     </tr>
```

Ao fazer um IF para comparar o numero no com 5 ou > , não consigo obter o valor. Estou fazendo referencia a tag de forma errada? gostaria de saber se há outra solução visto que uso uma table com SABOR e QUANTIDADE (strg e int)

Comment: Olá Ruan. Coloque na pergunta o código que vc tentou fazer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se sua tabela sempre segue essa regra, de ter duas *tds* por `tr` dentro do `tbody`, você consegue filtrar somente essa segunda `td` que possui o dados numérico.

Veja um exemplo de como fazer isso, utilizado o `querySelectorAll`, que vai retornar todos os elementos conforme o filtro informado:

```js
const tabela = document.querySelectorAll("tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)");

for(const dados of tabela) {
    if(dados.innerText > 5){
      dados.classList.add("vermelho");
    //Nesse exemplo, não é necessário o remove, mas fica de exemplo caso precise em sua implementação
    } else {
      dados.classList.remove("vermelho");
    }
}
```

```css
.vermelho {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody id ="tbl">
        <tr>  
            <td>açaí</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>     
        <tr>  
            <td>Coco</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Caso não deseje trabalhar com classes de css, você pode editar diretamente o estilo do elemento pela propriedade `style`:

```js
const tabela = document.querySelectorAll("tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)");

for(const dados of tabela) {
    if(dados.innerText > 5){
      dados.style.color = "red";
    }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody id ="tbl">
        <tr>  
            <td>açaí</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>     
        <tr>  
            <td>Coco</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

> Documentações:
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Eu acho que a minha maior dificuldade era realmente selecionar o "td" correto pois sim, sigo um padrão nos table rows. Obrigado pela resposta foi bem objetiva

Comment: boa resposta mas, pode adicionar mais informação do que é o seletor `nth-child`?